# Tensorflow hub error "cannot import name 'MomentumParameters' from 'tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tensorflow-hub

trying to use tensforflow hub on jupyter notebook, ive got the latest tensorflow installed.
However when i try to import tensorflow_hub `import tensorflow_hub as hub`, i get an error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'MomentumParameters' from 'tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding' (C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tpu\tpu_embedding.py)**

I've tried installing tensorflow hub on the anaconda cmd using `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-hub` and on jupyter using `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub`

here's the entire error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-14-5c017171c13e> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_hub as hub

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\__init__.py in <module>
     86 
     87 
---> 88 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
     89 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import register_module_for_export
     90 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import image_embedding_column

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\estimator.py in <module>
     60 
     61 
---> 62 class LatestModuleExporter(tf.compat.v1.estimator.Exporter):
     63   """Regularly exports registered modules into timestamped directories.
     64 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
     60 
     61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
     63     return getattr(module, item)
     64 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
     43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     47 

~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\api\_v1\estimator\__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import experimental
     11 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import export
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator import inputs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
     11 
     12 del _print_function

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py in <module>
     11 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import export
     12 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import inputs
---> 13 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import tpu
     14 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineClassifier
     15 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineEstimator

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\tpu\__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator.tpu import experimental
     11 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_config import InputPipelineConfig
     12 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu.tpu_config import RunConfig

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\tpu\experimental\__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.tpu._tpu_estimator_embedding import EmbeddingConfigSpec
     11 
     12 del _print_function

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\tpu\_tpu_estimator_embedding.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding import AdamParameters
     34 from tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding import FtrlParameters
---> 35 from tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding import MomentumParameters
     36 from tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding import RMSPropParameters
     37 from tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding import StochasticGradientDescentParameters

ImportError: cannot import name 'MomentumParameters' from 'tensorflow.python.tpu.tpu_embedding' (C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tpu\tpu_embedding.py)
```

Comment: Please specify the tensorflow and tensorflow versions you are using.

Comment: This seems to be connected to tensorflow/estimator@1d460d1

As a workaround, try using an estimator nightly version from before the commit instead:

pip uninstall tf-estimator-nightly tensorflow-estimator && pip install tf-estimator-nightly==2.4.0.dev2020101001

Answer (score 0):

I degrade my TensorFlow hub to version 2.3 ( the same as my tf GPU) and its works